# Regex to find variables inside curly braces of a Python JSON string

Tags: python, json

So I'm trying to extract variables from a python json string.

```
Input:
sample_string = '{{"some_key_1":"{var1}",
                   "some_key_2":"Hello this is {var2} from {var3}"
                  }}'

expected_output = ["var1","var2","var3]
```

I have tried searching for the same and have come across the following regex patterns.

```
1.re.findall(r"{(.*?)}", sample_string)
2.re.findall(r"{(.+?)}", sample_string)
```

However the output that I get is :

```
current_output = ['"some_key_1":"{var1','var2','var3']
```

**Note**: The reason why sample_string has two curly braces at start and end is because I am going to use string.format() on the same at a later stage to replace variables.

How do I get the expected output as shown above?

Comment: kindly check the first box.

Comment: Technically, that's not JSON. It looks like a string whose `format` method *might* (with the right arguments) return valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `[^{}]` that means no bracket chars

```
sample_string = '{{"s_1":"{var1}"," some_key_2": "Hello this is {var2} from {var3}"}}'
print(re.findall(r"{([^{}]*?)}", sample_string))  # ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
```

Comment: Yes that works, thanks, could you care to explain the pattern a bit more if possible?

Comment: @radix I can't say really more, `[abc]` accepts a,b,c char, `[^abc]` accepts everything except a,b and c, see doc here for example https://regex101.com/